# Substitute numpy functions with Python only

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have a python function that employs the numpy package. It uses numpy.sort and numpy.array functions as shown below:

```
def function(group):

    pre_data = np.sort(np.array(
        [c["data"] for c in group[1]], 
        dtype = np.float64
        ))
```

How can I re-write the sort and array functions using only Python in such a way that I no longer need the numpy package?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the code *after* this.  `pre_data` will be a `numpy.ndarray` which means that it has array methods which will be really hard to replicate without numpy.  If those methods are being called later in the code, you're going to have a hard time and I'd advise you to just bite the bullet and install `numpy`.  It's popularity is a testament to it's usefulness...

However, if you really just want to sort a list of floats and put it into a sequence-like container:

```
def function(group):
     pre_data = sorted(float(c['data']) for c in group[1])
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not strictly possible because the return type is an `ndarray`.  If you don't mind to use a list instead, try this:

```
pre_data = sorted(float(c["data"]) for c in group[1])
```

Comment: The return type is actually `NoneType` here, thanks to overzealous trimming by the OP!

Answer (score 1):

That's not actually using any useful numpy functions anyway

```
def function(group):
    pre_data = sorted(float(c["data"]) for c in group[1])
```